Javascript variable as the type of itself
I have an object with jsdoc annotations for the properties:
const foo = {
    /** @type {string[]} */
    bar: [],
    baz: {
        /**
         * @param {string} x
         * @returns {number}
         * @this {????}
         */
        bing(x) {
            this.bar.push(x);
            return 42;
        }
    }
};

// methods are invoked like so:
var method = "bing";
foo.baz[method].call(foo, "blah");

I need something to put in the @this tag for the method (in place of the ????), to express that the this argument will always be the top-level object, foo.
When I use infer foo, intellisense produces this for foo (the variable) itself:
const foo: {
    bar: string[];
    baz: {
        bing(this: foo, x: string): number;
    };
}

but this.bar inside the method is any.
When I use typeof foo -- which I think would work -- in place of the ????, intellisense only produces any for both foo and this.bar, which is even worse than I expected.
What typescript construct should I be using here?

You may need to explicitly declare a named type. If typeof foo does not work, that's probably because unnamed types cannot be recursive.

I added @typedef {typeof foo} foo, that didn't change anything...

I meant like type Foo = { bar: string[]; baz: { bing(this: Foo, x: string): number } } (and whatever the jsdoc equivalent of that is)
